# Optimization appending <li> into <ul> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I populate a list with search results appending **li** elements. I update DOM  for each result.

```
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    $("#searchResults").append(
        $("<li />")
            .append(result.Name)
            .addClass("example")
    );
};
```

I want to make a group of **li** elements first and update DOM-tree just once.

I try something like this:

```
var list = $([]);

for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    list.append(
        $("<li />")
            .append(result.Name)
            .addClass("example")
    );
};

$("#searchResults").append(list);
```

But div `$("#searchResults")` is empty.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should be much faster:

```
var ul = $("<ul />");
for (var i = 0, l=topics.length; i < l; i++) {
   $("<li />", { text: result.Name, "class": "example" }).appendTo(ul);
};
$("#searchResults").append(ul.contents());
```

By using a document fragment (`$("<ul />")`) and appending to it, then appending at the end, we're not messing with the entire DOM each append.  Also we're not repeatedly selecting `#searchResults` each loop...or checking `.length` would could also be expensive.

Note: this method still uses the DOM to create elements (as opposed to a string), eliminating issues of `result.Name` having HTML that could screw things up, etc.

Comment: I found the same solution. But I used $("#searchResults").append(ul.children()); Is it the same productivity? Profiler in firebug shows almost the same result. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @podeig - yup either would work here, `.contents()` is a more general approach for other situations (where the children may include text) :)

Comment: `$("<li class='example' />",...)` would be SLIGHTLY faster ;)

Comment: @gnarf - you can't have attributes in the html *and* in the props object, it'll error since it matches the wrong overload, try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try just using a string.  Add all your `li`'s to a string and then put them into the `innerHTML` of the `searchResults` div.

```
var list = '';

for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    list +="<li class=example>" + result.Name + "</li>";
}

$("#searchResults").innerHTML = list;
```

If you are looking for efficacy this is probably better because you are not using the DOM engines a lot.  (although unless you are adding hundreds of `li`'s it is probably insignificant anyway.

Comment: Good solution regarding optimization and productivity. I will optimize my code using this example in the future. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Creating DOM elements on the fly will usually be slower than just using innerHTML (or a wrapper around that). Also, concatenating string with `+` will usually be slower than using `Array.join('')`.

In the end, I suspect something like this would be the fastest:

```
var list = [];

for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) 
    list.push("<li class=example>",topics[i].Name,"</li>");

$("#searchResults").html(list.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

All previous solutions still suffer from recalculating, painting and layout for every single element we add.

Instead of appending the elements directly to the document when they are created, append them to the `DocumentFragment` instead, and finish by adding that to the DOM.

```
var el;
var i = 0;
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

while (i < 500) {
    el = document.createElement('li');
    el.innerText = '1ist ' + i;
    fragment.appendChild(el);
    i++;  
}

div.appendChild(fragment);
```